# Override tf.floor gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to use tf.floor in my output layer, but keep getting "None gradient" error even if I tried to override it with identity gradient.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

def transfer(x):
    with tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph() as g:
        with g.gradient_override_map({'Floor': 'Identity'})
            return tf.floor(x * 90) / 90

input = keras.layers.Input((10, ))
output = keras.layers.Lambda(transfer)(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(input))
```

Here is the full error message:

```
/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
   1037   if not filtered:
   1038     raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %
-> 1039                      ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))
   1040   if vars_with_empty_grads:
   1041     logging.warning(

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
```

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message.

Comment: Please see the updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using TF 2? I highly doubt this graph stuff will do anything, because TF 2.0 doesn't really do graphs anymore. The standard way to override gradients is via [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient?version=stable). You would use it like this:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def custom_floor(x):
    def grad_fn(dy):
        return dy

    return tf.floor(x), grad_fn
```

Then, use the `custom_floor` function instead of `tf.floor` in your model. This will return `tf.floor` (the first return element) in the forward pass, but use `grad_fn` (the second return element) to compute the gradient -- in this case it will just pass it through unchanged. You could of course also apply the `@custom_gradient` directly to your `transfer` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've another question about none gradeint in a custom loss function. Could you also help, thank you very much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667300/no-gradient-in-custom-loss-function