# No gradient in custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to create a custom loss function using spearman correlation in tensorflow 2.1.0-rc1. However, I've encountered "no gradient" error. I have multiple targets. To avoid spearman giving `nan` for labels with only one unique value, I just pass and did nothing. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

def spear_func(a, b):
    return spearmanr(a, b).correlation.astype('float32')

def custom_loss(num_targets):
    def custom_rhos(y_true, y_pred):
        rhos = tf.constant(0, dtype='float32')
        for ind in range(num_targets):
            a = tf.slice(y_true, [0, ind], [-1, 1])
            a = tf.reshape(a, [-1])
            b = tf.slice(y_pred, [0, ind], [-1, 1])
            b = tf.reshape(b, [-1])
            rhos = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.argmax(a), tf.argmin(a)),
                    lambda: rhos, # <-- Here is the problem
                    lambda: tf.subtract(rhos,
                        tf.compat.v1.py_func(spear_func, [a, b], Tout=tf.float32)))
        return rhos
    return custom_rhos
```

The error message is:

```
/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
   1037   if not filtered:
   1038     raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %
-> 1039                      ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))
   1040   if vars_with_empty_grads:
   1041     logging.warning(

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
```

I tried to write my own spearman function. But it sill gives the same error.

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata
BATCH_SIZE = 4

def custom_loss(num_targets):
    def custom_rhos(y_true, y_pred):
        rhos = []
        for ind in range(num_targets):
            a = tf.squeeze(tf.slice(y_true, [0, ind], [-1, 1]))
            # a = tf.reshape(a, [-1])
            b = tf.squeeze(tf.slice(y_pred, [0, ind], [-1, 1]))
            # b = tf.reshape(b, [-1])
            rank_a, rank_b = tf.numpy_function(rankdata, [a],  Tout=tf.float32), tf.numpy_function(rankdata, [b],  Tout=tf.float32)
            rho = 1 - 6 * tf.reduce_sum((rank_a - rank_b) ** 2) / (BATCH_SIZE ** 3 - BATCH_SIZE)
            rhos.append(rho)
        return -tf.reduce_sum(rhos)
    return custom_rhos
```

Comment: Constants don't have gradients (they are not related to the weights of your model), you can't return constants in a loss function. Also, `spearmanr` is not a tensor function, it's from an unrelated package and, because of that, it doesn't have gradients defined (the system will not be able to guess the gradients for this function).

Comment: @DanielMöller. I could run the spearmanr along with binary crossentropy (see above). Is there a way to just use spearmanr even the condition is met in tf.cond?

Comment: I don't think so. You should probably write your own `spearmanr` using `tf` or `keras` functions.

Comment: @DanielMöller. Thanks for your suggestions. Could you take a look at my function, it still didn't work even if I write my own spearmanr

Comment: As said before, functions from external packages are not differentiable because tensorflow cannot guess what the derivative should be. You can read this in the limitations here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function